# Django ORM doesn't save value when referencing to them by child attributes

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-1.7

Today I found something very tricky. I use django 1.7.7 (if this is important).

I have two models in relation: `Car` and `Driver`. I want to connect with each other instances of car object and driver object. Both objects seems(*****) to be already created.

In both cases:

```
car = Car.objects.create()
car.save()
driver = Driver.objects.create()
driver.save()

self.garage.car = car
self.garage.save()
```

and next:

```
# doesn't work
self.garage.car.driver = driver
self.garage.car.save()
# self.object.car.driver is None
```

but:

```
# works
car = self.garage.car
car.driver = driver
car.save()
# self.object.car.driver is driver
```

(*****) - To be honest I am not sure, whether these objects are fully created or not yet. Everything is going on in View, both objects have already own `id`s, however manual query to database shows, that those objects are not yet present. Transaction is not finished?

Comment: Where is this code, exactly?

Comment: What is `self` and what is `object` in your example? I would expect the API to be something like `car =Car(); car.driver = Driver(...)`.

Comment: @IanAuld: I think this is not important. `self` is a instance of View, object is another instance of model, lets sey `garage`. @Daniel: code is in CreateView.form_valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your sample code, first self.object.car is not the same object you save in the line below. Check this out:

```
self.garage.car is self.garage.car
```

If above is False the only explanation is that car is a property and you get new instance of object every time you call this property.

Comment: why is that? Is it new in Django 1.7?